# Flutter InAppWebView does not allow non english content in textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm having a weird issue with the Flutter InAppWebView plugin version 4.0.0+4 here https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview where I try to load the simple contact us form into the plugin and realize that I can't enter the content into html input text field if I use non English keyboard, in my case I use Vietnamese keyboard. If I switch the keyboard to English one then its working. I double checked the contact us form and made sure its working 100% on Chrome browser outside of the Flutter app using even non English keyboard. I don't use any special code or settings for the plugin, just same as the one mentioned in the pub.dev. I'm using Flutter channel stable v. 1.22.6

This is my code in case you need it:

```
class WebViewerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, String> metaData;

  WebViewerWidget({this.metaData});

  @override
  _WebViewerWidgetState createState() => _WebViewerWidgetState();
}

class _WebViewerWidgetState extends State<WebViewerWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InAppWebViewController _webviewCtrl;
    double progressIndicator = 0;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorPalette.white,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          child: TopNavWidget(
            title: widget.metaData['title'] ?? '',
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
        ),
        body: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      child: progressIndicator < 1
                          ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                              value: progressIndicator,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
                              valueColor:
                                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                            )
                          : Container()),
                  Expanded(
                    child: InAppWebView(
                      initialUrl: widget.metaData['url'] ?? 'about:blank',
                      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          debuggingEnabled: true,
                          javaScriptEnabled: true,
                          useShouldInterceptAjaxRequest: true,
                          useShouldInterceptFetchRequest: true,
                        ),
                        ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(),
                        android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(),
                      ),
                      onWebViewCreated:
                          (InAppWebViewController webviewController) {
                        _webviewCtrl = webviewController;
                      },
                      onProgressChanged:
                          (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                        setState(() {
                          progressIndicator = progress / 100;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, now I've noticed that it will start working when I ignore the first text field on the form which is in this case the user's full name, just jump straight into the next text field which is email, type something in here then go back to user full name, this time it allows me to enter Vietnamese characters. So weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after spending a couple days fixing the issue, I had to give up on this one. Its definitely a bug from the plugin, found someone had the similar issue here `https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/560`. I then tried another plugin called WebView `https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed with new version [`5.0.0`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) (the latest version now is [`5.0.5+3`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)): use `useHybridComposition: true` Android-specific webview option, all the issues related to the Android keyboard are fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Lorenzo. Will try it again.

Comment: still not works in emulator